# Bootstrap3 dropdown issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this in my HTML , I am using bootstrap 3 classes to make a drop down with in another drop down.

```
<div class="subnav">
 <ul class="nav-pills">
   <li class="dropdown" style="float: right;">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" >
      <span id="spnUsrName">Welcome, {{usrName}}</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
     <li class="disabled" ><a href="#">Disabled link 1</a></li>
     <li class="disabled" ><a href="#">Disabled link 2</a></li>
     <li class="divider"></li>
     <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">Settings</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Change Password</a></li></ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#" ng-click="UserLogout()">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

However, the 'ul' inside the first dropdown-meu is not showing up. The "Settings" option is displayed, but change password option is not displayed. Where have I gone wrong.

Comment: I referred to http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html.

Comment: Okay, I know, I am referring to 2.3.2 and not 3. But is there a work around?

Comment: Hi Refer this link for bootstrap drop-down guide [**Bootstrap Dropdown**](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3)

Comment: I better suggest to use version 3 .
here is a link for you .
http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-dropdowns.php